# Using Filters Laravel Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to filter by shops.

**Controller**

```html
function filter(Request $request){
    $goods = Good::select('shop_id')->where('shop_id', '=', $request->id)->get();
    $shops = Shop::all ();
    return view('filter')->with(['goods' => $goods, 'shops' => $shops]);
}
```

**Migrations**

```html
Schema::create('goods', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('amount');
    $table->integer('shop_id');
    $table->timestamp('onPurchase');
    $table->timestamps();
});
      
Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('adress')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Form to get id**

```html
<form action = "{{ route('filter') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select name="id">
    @foreach ($shops as $shop)
        <option value="{{$shop->id}}">{{$shop->name}} {{$shop->adress}}</option>
    @endforeach;
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pasirinkti">
</form>
```

It won't print the list based on the selected ID that I get via $_POST. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's just be, but I do not get what the problem is? What do you want to achieve? What is / why is it not working? Any exceptions / error messages? Please help us to help you. :)

Comment: below the form i have @foreach that prints the list. The output should be Goods list based on the shop selected ($_POST['id]. However, i do not get any values in the table. No errors (this is what frustrates me). Errors would be helpful at this point :)

Comment: @benua your filtering the `goods` correctly by the shop id, at the same time fetching all the shops in another query. So as per your code the `$goods` will contains the goods from the selected shop. Also you might want to fetch all the data and not just `shop_id` on `goods`. `$goods = Good::where('shop_id', $request->id)->get();`

Comment: it works, but only once :) whey i try to change the shop - list becomes empty. However, for the first selection - it works perfectly.